# Generic UserControl (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, generic-collections

I'm making WPF user control that would allow to edit (add, reorder, remove) items of `ListBox` bound to `ObservableCollection<TextItem>` (where `TextItem` is a wrapper over string type for `TwoWay` binding but that doesn't matter). Now I want my control to be able to work with `ObservableCollection` independently on it's items type. What is the best way to rework `ListEditingButtons` to `ListEditingButtons<T>`? As I understand, I should make generic class derived from `UserControl` and then inherit concrete classes from it. Then how can I keep XAML in base class, what changes will it require? I'm using .NET 4.0.

Or maybe there's a ready-made implementation of such a control?

Comment: UI is not data. WPF does not care what your data items are. You need to provide a proper DataTemplate for each item type. Your UI elements (whatever classes derived from `FrameworkElement`) should NOT be generic. This is, these classes should not have a type parameter.

Comment: HighCore is correct. You should google for "Model-View View Model" which is probably the most famous pattern to display data in your views using Microsofts most modern UI frameworks. Your attempt seems somewhat complicated and does not leverage the potential of these frameworks.